# Selenium web-driver 2 don't work

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I used eclipse Luna, Mozilla and web driver 2. I tried open a broswer withs localhost and tried created a new element.

**My error**
selenium cannont be resolved

```
package secondProject;
public class CreacionSimpleUbicacion {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    //private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://localhost/cmmsv3/publico/ordenestrabajo/inicio/index";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUbicacion2() throws Exception {
        selenium.click("id=mnt-menu");
        selenium.click("link=Ubicación");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("3000");
        selenium.click("link=Listado Ubicaciones");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("3000");

        for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
            try { if (selenium.isElementPresent("id=top_nav_panel_ListaUbicacion")) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        verifyEquals("Crear", selenium.getText("id=accionn"));
        selenium.click("id=accionn");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("3000");
        selenium.click("id=btnAceptar");
        verifyEquals("El registro no pudo ser guardado!", selenium.getText("css=p"));
        verifyEquals("El campo Nombre no puede estar vacío", selenium.getText("css=#fv_error_nombre > span"));
        verifyEquals("El campo Nombre Corto no puede estar vacío", selenium.getText("css=#fv_error_nomshort > span"));
        selenium.type("id=nombre", "Ubicacion Simple");
        selenium.type("id=nomshort", "ubs");
        selenium.click("id=btnAceptar");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("3000");

        for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
            try { if (selenium.isElementPresent("css=p")) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        verifyEquals("La Ubicación se creó satisfactoriamente.", selenium.getText("css=p"));
        verifyEquals("Ubicacion Simple", selenium.getValue("id=nombre"));
        verifyEquals("ubs", selenium.getValue("id=nomshort"));
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this?  It looks to be Java, but that you might have pasted the wrong version from the selenium IDE.  If you just put driver.findElement(By.id("mnt-menu")).click(); in the testUbicacion2 method, does it work?

Comment: Yes it's java, so i have to chage selenium i wirte driver.click for example

Comment: @KarinaSerrano make sure to add all possible tags. You can add up to 5 different tags if I am not mistaking. That increases the chance of getting answered sooner

Comment: BTW, what is `selenium` here?

Comment: Yes, you will have to change all the functions to a variation of driver.findElement(byselectorGoeshere).methodcall.

Comment: Code seems a mix and match of Selenium 1 & WebDriver 2. Why?

Comment: Hi @BrianHoover you are right, i exported my code from selenium ide in format J4Unit/Webdriver and works!.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing [selenium-rc](/questions/tagged/selenium-rc) and [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) APIs in an [unsupported](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_migrating_from_rc_to_webdriver.jsp) way.

You initialize your test with Selenium-WebDriver:

```
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

But then you start using Selenium-RC:

```
    selenium.click("id=mnt-menu");
```

This is not going to work! You need to pick one and stick to it. I recommend [Selenium-WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp), since Selenium-RC is deprecated now, and will soon be obsoleted.